# need help {discord bot}}

Tags: javascript, discord

I want to start my Bot but it dont work and i tried already the most things but nothing worked for me!!! I hope you can help me.

The Code:

```
client.on('ready', async () => {
log.success(`Authenticated as ${client.user.tag}`);
client.user.setPresence({
    activity: {
        name: env.PRESENCE_ACTIVITY,
        type: env.PRESENCE_TYPE.toUpperCase()
    }
})
if (client.guilds.cache.get(env.GUILD_ID).member(client.user).hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR', false)) {
    log.success('Bot has the \'ADMINISTRATOR\' permission');
} else log.warn('Bot does not have \'ADMINISTRATOR\' permission');
client.guilds.cache.get(env.GUILD_ID).roles.fetch().then((roles) => {
    purchasedRole = roles.cache.get(env.PURCHASED_ROLE_ID);
});
```

});

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'member')
at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Discord-Bot\index.js:308:46)
at Client.emit (node:events:527:28)
at WebSocketManager.triggerClientReady (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Discord-Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:431:17)
at WebSocketManager.checkShardsReady (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Discord-Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:415:10)
at WebSocketShard.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Discord-Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:197:14)
at WebSocketShard.emit (node:events:527:28)
at WebSocketShard.checkReady (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Discord-Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:475:12)
at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Discord-Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:447:16)
at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Discord-Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Discord-Bot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in `client.guilds.cache.get(env.GUILD_ID).member(client.user)`.

Its not `member` its the plural `members` as you can see [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Guild?scrollTo=members)

I don't know if `client.user` works here so maybe try `client.user.id`

Comment: `code`
if (client.guilds.cache.get(env.GUILD_ID).members(client.user.id).hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR', false)) {
                                             ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'members')
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Discord-Bot\index.js:308:46)

Comment: already tried to await the members?